# Naming or extracting segments as geometrical objects from polygons

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I have this little issue that I can't really make a good solution for. I have this dataframe:

```
index                                    id  x_polygon  y_polygon  \
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  44.863280   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  44.863280   

                               edges.id  
0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3  
0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7  
0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d  
0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3  
0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7  
0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d  
0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3  
0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7  
0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d  
0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3  
0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7  
0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d
```

which gives the coordinates of edges of polygons (in this particualr case, it is one single polygon). The `id` is the name of the polygon and `edges.id` is the id id of each edge in theis polygon. Now, I ususally only look att the polygon and I usually use geopandas to transform this data into POLYGON obeject to work with, doing this:

```
geostore_obstacles_geometry = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geostore_obstacles.groupby(['id']).apply(
    lambda g: Polygon(gpd.points_from_xy(g['x_polygon'], g['y_polygon']))))
```

But now, I realize that I actually would like to work with each vertice in this polygon as if they where independent polygons. This means that I no longer can groupby id as I do. So, I need to define a column giving a name to each vertice, preferably using the edge name as a base. My initial idea was to check the difference between `x_polygon` and `y_polygon` values between consecutive rows. For instance

```
 index                                    id  x_polygon  y_polygon  \
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   

                               edges.id  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d
```

would give me one of the lines since the values of `x_polygon` are different while the others are not. So, I thought of doing this

```
geostore_obstacles_0['Diff_x'] = np.abs(round(geostore_obstacles_0.groupby('id')['x_polygon'].diff().fillna(1),0))
geostore_obstacles_0 = geostore_obstacles_0.sort_values(['index','edges.id'])
geostore_obstacles_0['Diff_y'] = np.abs(round(geostore_obstacles_0.groupby('id')['y_polygon'].diff().fillna(1),0))
```

which gives

```
index                                    id  x_polygon  y_polygon  \
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  32.987843  37.251873   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3  33.567165  37.251873   

                               edges.id  Diff_x  Diff_y  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d     0.0     1.0  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d     0.0     0.0
```

There are two problems:

1. I do not know what to do with it to give a name to that feature
2. This fails if (an it might happen), any of the polygon aren't at 0 or 90 degrees angles.

One approach I would love to have is to pick each individual segment from the geopandas polygons.

I know there is a package called `gemgis` to explode polygons, but it has a dependency on `rasterio` which I fail to install.